# Why does my Elseif function not work? Errormessage: Compile Error: Else without if

Tags: vba

```
Sub exercise2d()

Dim taxamount As String
Dim income As String

Range("A10:A11").NumberFormatLocal = "##.#0,00 ?"
income = Range("A10").Value

If income <= 12000 Then taxamount = income * 0.12
ElseIf income <= 20000 Then taxamount = income * 0.15
ElseIf income <= 30000 Then taxamount = income * 0.2
Else: taxamount = income * 0.25
End If

Range("A11").Value = taxamount

End Sub
```

Comment: move the `taxmount  = ...` onto a new line

Comment: See top-voted answer in linked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some brackets and apparently, the command from the `then` must be placed at a new line:

```
If (income <= 12000) Then
  taxamount = income * 0.12
ElseIf (income <= 20000) Then
  taxamount = income * 0.15
ElseIf (income <= 30000) Then
  taxamount = income * 0.2
Else:
  taxamount = income * 0.25
End If
```